# How can i store the values of array_count_values in array of object?

Tags: php, arrays

i have array like below which is sorted by array_count_values function,

```
Array
(
    [Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)#1 only: 1pmADV] => 3
    [Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM)#1 only: 2pmADV] => 2
    [Session #4: Tues July 12th - Fri July 22nd (9-2:00PM)#1 only: 1:30pmADV] => 2

)
```

i need to convert this array into array of object like below,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Itemname] => Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)#1 only: 1pmADV
    [Quantity] => 3
)

stdClass Object
(
    [Itemname] => Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM)#1 only: 2pmADV
    [Quantity] => 2
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Itemname] => Session #4: Tues July 12th - Fri July 22nd (9-2:00PM)#1 only: 1:30pmADV
    [Quantity] => 2
)
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arrayOfObjects = array();
foreach ($values as $Itemname => $Quantity) {
    $arrayOfObjects[] = (object)compact('Itemname', 'Quantity');
}
```

Comment: Big +1 for for using [`compact()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $object = new stdClass;
    $object->Itemname = $key;
    $object->Quantity = $value;
    print_r($object);
}
```